# Remove last column from a csv file in Perl

Tags: linux, perl

I have a Perl script that accepts a comma separated csv file as input.
I would like to discard the last column (the column number is known in advance).

The problem is that the last column may contain quoted strings with commas, in which case I would like to cut the entire string.

Example:

```
colA,colB,colC
1,2,3
4,5,"6,6"
```

What I would like to end up with is:

```
colA,colB
1,2
4,5
```

The current solution I have is using Linux cut command in the following manner:

```
cat $file | cut -d ',' -f 3 --complement
```

Which outputs the following:

```
colA,colB
1,2
4,5,6"
```

Which works great unless the last column is a quoted string with commas in it.

I can only use native Perl/Linux commands to solve this.

Appreciate your help

Comment: If the right approach was to call an external tool like cut, sed, or awk then perl would be a very sad little tool.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV), as a script to process STDIN into STDOUT:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV 'csv';

my $csv = csv(in => \*STDIN, keep_headers => \my @headers,
  auto_diag => 2, encoding => 'UTF-8');

pop @headers;

csv(in => $csv, out => \*STDOUT, headers => \@headers,
  auto_diag => 2, encoding => 'UTF-8');
```

The obvious benefit of this approach is handling all common edge cases automatically.

Comment: That's the cleanest and easiest solution. Don't re-invent the wheel, especially not with unreadable regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this based on [awk-regex](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html):

```
awk -v FPAT='([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")'  -v OFS=',' '{print $1,$2}' ${file}
```

***Example***

```
echo '"4,4",5,"6,6"' | awk -v FPAT='([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")'  -v OFS=',' '{print $1,$2}'
"4,4",5
```

Reference

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This works for a single line, but will cut unneccesary data on a a complete file. Update my post with a more thorough example

Comment: This is better, but there is a corner case if the first or second column contains quoted data, ie 
colA,colB,colC
1,2,3
"4,4",5,"6,6"

Answer (score 1):

If quoted strings with comma is the only trouble you are facing, you can use this:

```
$ sed -E 's/,"[^"]*"$|,[^,]*$//' ip.txt
colA,colB
1,2
4,5
```

- `,"[^"]*"$` will match `,` followed by `"` followed by non `"` characters followed by `"` at the end of line
- `,[^,]*$` will match `,` followed by non `,` characters at end of line

The double quoted column will match earlier in the string and thus gets deleted completely

Equivalent for `perl` would be `perl -lpe 's/,"[^"]*"$|,[^,]*$//' ip.txt`

Answer (score 1):

I believe [sungtm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8113769/sungtm) answer is correct and requries some  explanation:

```
awk -v FPAT='([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")'  -v OFS=',' '{print $1,$2}'
```

Is equivalent to:

#### script.awk

```
BEGIN {
    FPAT = "([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")"; # gnu awk specific: FPAT is RegEx pattern to identify the field's content
    # [^,]+ ------ RegEx pattern to match all chars not ","
    #"[^\"]+\" ------ RegEx pattern to match all quated chars including the quotes
    #()|() ------ RegEx optional groups selector
    OFS = ","; # Output field separator
}
{ # for each input line/record
    print $1, $2; # print "1st field" OFS value "2nd field"
}
```

#### Runnig

```
awk -f scirpt.awk input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the script in any file say script.pl
Execute as prompt>perl script.pl /opt/filename.csv

- "1","2,3",4,"test, test" ==> "1","2,3",4
- 1,"2,3,4","5 , 6","7,8" ==>  1,"2,3,4","5 , 6"
- 0,0,0,"test" ==> 0,0,0

Handles above cases

```
use strict;
if (scalar(@ARGV) != 1 ) {
    print "usage: perl script.pl absolute_file_path";
    exit;
}
my $filename = $ARGV[0]; # complete file path here
open(DATA, '<', $filename)
    or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";

my @lines = <DATA>;
close(DATA);

my $counter=0;
open my $fo, '>', $filename;



foreach my $line(@lines) {
    chomp($line);

    my @update = split '(?:^|,)(\"(?:[^\"]+|\"\")*\"|[^,]*)' , $line;
    my @update2;
    foreach (@update) {
       if($_=~/\w+/) {
           push(@update2,$_);
       }
    }
    pop(@update2);
    print @update2;
    my $str = join(',',@update2);
    print $fo "$str";
    unless (++$counter == scalar(@lines)) {
        print $fo "\n";
    }
}
close $fo;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this case is quite interesting - please see my solution bellow.

You can change `$debug = 1;` to see what happens and how this mechanism works

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $debug = 0;

while( <DATA> ) {
    print "IN:  $_" if $debug;
    chomp;

    s/"(.+?)"/replace($1)/ge;   # do magic replacement , -> ___ in block of interest

    print "REP: $_\n" if $debug;

    my @data = split /,/;       # split into array
    pop @data;                  # pop last element of array

    my $line = join ',', @data; # merge array into a string

    $line =~ s/___/,/g;         # do unmagic replacement
    $line =~ s/\|/"/g;          # restore | -> "

    printf "%s$line\n", $debug ? "OUT: " : '';  # print result
}

sub replace {
    my $line = shift;

    $line =~ s/,/___/g;         # do magic replacement in our block

    return "|$line|";           # put | arount block of interest
}

__DATA__
colA,colB,colC
1,2,3
4,5,"6,6"
8,3,"1,2",37,82
64,12,"1,2,3,4",42,56
"3,4,7,8",2,8,"8,7,6,5,4",2,8
"3,4,7,8",2,8,"8,7,6,5,4",2,8,"2,8,4,1"
"3,4,7,8",2,8,"8,7,6,5,4",2,8,"2,8,4,1",3,4
```

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate your help. Below is the solution I ended up using:

```
cat file.csv | perl -MText::ParseWords -nle '@f = parse_line(",",2, $_); tr/,/$/d for @f; print join ",", @f' | cut -d ',' -f 3 --complement | tr $ , ;
```

This will replace commas in field surrounded by quotes to the $ sign, to re replaced back after discarding the last unwanted column.